# Getting an Facebook user profile data with Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook

I need to get a facebook user uid , gender, photo and other profile data with Javascript.

I remember there was a method to get an user object with .id, .gender, .photo but I haven't got a copy of the API call and I can't find an explanation in the documentation.

How do I get the user UID and gender with Javascript ?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update: I added a little more detail to the answer:**

First, you need to call FB.init and add your app id:

```
FB.init(
{
    appId  : APP_ID,
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
});
```

Next, check if there is a session open (i.e., the user is logged in)

```
if(FB.getSession() != null) {
```

And query the details by:

```
    FB.api('/me', function(response) 
    {
        alert ("Welcome " + response.name + ": Your UID is " + response.id); 
    });
}
```

You will also need to add `<div id="fb-root"></div>` to the `<body>` of your page, and load `<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>`

The user profile picure can be accessed as `http:/graph.facebook.com/USERID/picture/`

Check the Graph API reference here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

and the FB SDK reference here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Comment: @gary Added on behalf of Aleadam

Comment: Thanks, but this function is deprecated. use `FB.getLoginStatus` instead.

Comment: How to get user address? should i use response.address?

Answer (score 22):

The function `FB.getSession()` used in the accepted answer to this question in 2011 is now (2012) deprecated and removed from the Facebook JS SDK.

You can still discover the user's Facebook ID with the `getLoginStatus()` method like this:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    alert ("Your UID is " + response.authResponse.userID);
  }
});
```

Note: you still have to init the Facebook API and put the `fb-root` element in your HTML, like Aleadam explained in the accepted answer.

Comment: Your solution works, but there is a little mistake. I used fb.login() and there you have to use response.authResponse.userId instead of userID. 
Still thanks alot saved me from a big trouble. upvoted:)

Comment: Weird. Both my local test and Facebook's documentation work with an uppercase D. See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/ .

Comment: Its really weird now, because here its not working  with uppercase :D

Answer (score 0):

In the [authorization parameter](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/appcenter/#authorization) of your app, ensure that the **Auth Token** Parameter is configured as **URI Fragment**.

The login process using [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) is explained in the [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) documentation there : [Getting started with Facebook login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/getting-started-web/).

Follow the **three steps**, source code is already written.