# how to obtain scope information for facebook login button?

Tags: javascript, facebook, scope

I created a facebook login button from here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/

and I have the following login button:

```
 <div class="fb-login-button" scope="email" data-show-faces="true" data-max-rows="3">Login with Facebook</div>
```

So, when the user accept the permissions, how can I get the user information (in this case the email)? (Using javazcript in client-side)

Comment: Duplicate of his own closed question: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11620797/i-would-like-to-know-how-to-retreive-the-email-adress-with-a-facebook-login-butt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to:

[Get user's Facebook UID with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846752/facebook-get-users-facebook-uid-with-javascript)
but you will need to take this a little further and get their email by looking for `email` in the response object.

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    var email = response.email;
});
```

However, your app will have to request this permission from your users, see Facebook documentation on permissions here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

Comment: The script as is is not working into my site. I don't know why is not entering the function. Anyway it was a very good and clear answer for my problem. I will investigate more based on this. Thank you very much.