# Facebook API - Get user login info

Tags: facebook, api

I have an application where the App permissions are set to use "None (default)", this because I don't want the user to go through the step of authenticating the app, as my app is available for public use (for users without Facebook login).

I do however want the Facebook uID of the user who is logged into Facebook to customize something on page. I tried the FB.api('/me', callback) method, but the response returned for both name and uid is 'undefined'.

I use Javascript SDK. Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: URL of the app permissions screen here: http://i45.tinypic.com/2u7vgqg.png

Comment: Try this question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846752/facebook-get-users-facebook-uid-with-javascript

Answer (score 2):

> I do however want the Facebook uID of the user who is logged into Facebook to customize something on page. I tried the FB.api('/me', callback) method, but the response returned for both name and uid is 'undefined'.

Well, that’s because the API can’t know who “me” is supposed to be without a user access token – and since you don’t want the user to connect to your app, you will not get one of those.

You **can not** get the user’s id if you don’t have them connect to your app first.

Comment: Hi CBroe, Thanks for the information. Is there something else that I can use to mark this user as unique? again, not the computer, but the user who is logged in.

Comment: Not without the user interacting with your app in any way.