# Get current logged in facebook userId

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, facebook-graph-api, plugins

This is close to the question asked [Getting an Facebook user profile data with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846752/facebook-get-users-facebook-uid-with-javascript) here, but I am not looking to interface at all with anything more than the publically available facebook API info.  For example, if you navigate to http://graph.facebook.com/ericfusciardi  you will see my public facebook id, and public name supplied to facebook -- no credential or API token required.

Is there a way to obtain the current logged in username OR userid without needing to create an "app" in facebook and registering the SDK / jump through all its API hoops [ which only seems relevent to apps wanting to dig deeper than public info ]?  My plugin is only interested in the public information.  Is the ID/name stored in a cookie or something?  If so, where can it be reliably located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use whatever API you desire, but to get this information, it is held in the facebook.com cookie ... attribute name is "c_user"  -- It contains a long value that you can use to query `graph.facebook.com` for relevent data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the user id of the **current** user, you need the **access token** of that user (the only way).

Now, to get the access token the user must **login-in with facebook** (again, the only way to get the access token)

And finally, to integrate "login with facebook", you have to create an **App**. (but I guess its not a big deal, is it?)

Comment: Incorrect.  After some digging on the local filesystem, I found out to get the user-id of the current user, i need to query the `c_user` attribute of the facebook.com cookie.  No access tokens necessary.  Thanks anyhow.

Comment: Great, but I dont think this is reliable enough

Comment: It may be, as it is undocumented... but it circumvents the complexity of adding the FB library, registering for an ID, and managing lifecycle.  So for now, I'll take it.  All im interested in is the same data that could be queried from the public graph, so this is a win.