# Getting the name of the player on facebook

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, facebook

i have a prompt to ask the player his name to send his score to the leaderboard of a game on facebook canvas.

```
var playerName = prompt("You earned "+score.toString()+" points. Please enter your name:", "player");
$.get("scoreboard.php",{"player": playerName, "score": score.toString()})
.done(function(data){console.log(data);});
```

what code should i implement to get his name automatically from facebook and send to my database?

I have already implemented:

```
    function getMe(callback) {
  FB.api('/me', {fields: 'id,name,first_name,picture.width(100).height(100)'}, function(response){
    if( !response.error ) {
      friendCache.me = response;
      callback();
    } else {
      console.error('/me', response);
    }
  });
```

but how i retrieve this information on playerName ????

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5846796/1793718 might be helpful.

Comment: use facebook SDK. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

Comment: If that solved your question please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

simple: var playerName = friendCache.me.first_name;